# How to count letters before cursor in bash using linux c?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

For example , "[root@localhost ~]# asd" , the number before cursor should be strlen("[root@localhost ~]# asd" ) , while the cursor is after letter 'd' .

Comment: Not happening. bash has no facility for this.

Comment: It is true that you can't get PS1 from within bash (at least not without a silly amount of work), but OP wants to do this from within C. With access to the source anything is possible!

Comment: Why do you want to count it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: `bash` doesn't, but the Linux console does. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could call some of the functions provided in the bash headers, as shown in [this blog post](http://powerfield-software.com/?p=116).

It might be as simple as something like:

```
#include <config.h>
#include "../bashtypes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../bashintl.h"
#include "../shell.h"
#include "common.h"

...
int getPS1Len () {
  char *ps1 = get_string_value ("PS1");
  if (ps1 != 0) {
    ps1 = decode_prompt_string (ps1);
    if (ps1 != 0) {
      return strlen(ps1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
...
```

(Totally untested code, copied with some changes from the linked post.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the linux console or a VT-100 emulator with similar emulation (konsole and xterm, for example), then you can query the current cursor position by writing the following ECMA-48 control sequence to the terminal.

```
ESC [ 6 n
```

where `ESC` is hexadecimal code `1b`. The terminal will respond with the sequence:

```
ESC [ ## ; ## R
```

where the first `##` is the row number and the second `##` is the column number of the cursor location, both expressed as decimal numbers without leading zeros.

Here's an example, to show how it works (no C code, just shell):

```
$ IFS= read -p "This is a prompt: "$'\e[6n' -dR -rs CURSOR; read -r RESPONSE
This is a prompt: Hello, world!
$ hd <<<"$CURSOR"
00000000  1b 5b 33 38 3b 31 39 0a                           |.[38;19.|
00000008
$ hd <<<"$RESPONSE"
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77  6f 72 6c 64 21 0a        |Hello, world!.|
0000000e
```

The first command-line, consisting of two `read` commands does the following:

1. Print the string `This is a prompt:` followed by the cursor query console code. (`-p PROMPT` command-line option to `read`)
2. Read the input up to the first `R` (`-dR` command-line option), storing it in the shell variable `CURSOR`. This input is *not* echoed back to the terminal (`-s` command-line option).
3. Read a line of input, storing it in the shell variable `RESPONSE`

From the query response stored in `CURSOR`, you can see that the cursor (prior to my typing `Hello, world!`) was at column 19 of row 38.

You could do exactly the same thing from the inside of a programmable-completion function, for example. I'm not sure how else you could run a program in the middle of terminal input, but if you can figure out how to run a program, that program can issue the cursor position query and read the query report, as above.